# I want to check if something is in/not in a nested list

Tags: list, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, nested

I hope you can help look at the code

```
sheros=[['Groot',23,34,35],['Rocket',45,56,67]]

print(sheros)
newname=input('what is your name? ' )
newstat=int(input('what is the new stat? ' ))

listlength=len(sheros)

while listlength!=0:
    if sheros[listlength-1][0]==newname:
        sheros[listlength-1][3]=sheros[listlength-1][2]
        sheros[listlength-1][2]=sheros[listlength-1][1]
        sheros[listlength-1][1]=newstat
        listlength-=1
    else:
        listlength-=1

#this is the part doing my head in!
if newname in sheros:
    print('already here')
else:
    sheros+=[[newname,newstat,0,0]]
print('added')

print(sheros)
```

I want it so that if the named person is already in the list it adds their new stat to the list of 3 and pushed out the oldest one (got that sorted in the while loop) but I then want to add the person to the end of the nested list if they don't appear yet (new entry), see the bit that says #this is the part doing my head in!

Is it too late, have I had too much gin?

Please help my brain hurts

Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def main():
    sheros = [['Groot',23,34,35],['Rocket',45,56,67]]

    print(sheros)
    newname = input('what is your name? ' )
    newstat = int(input('what is the new stat? ' ))

    found = False  # Use a flag to track whether name was found
    for entry in sheros:  # Don't use counter. Just loop over elements.
        if entry[0] == newname:
            entry[2:4] = entry[1:3]  # Use list slicing
            entry[1] = newstat
            found = True
            break  # Exit early assuming names are unique.

    if found:
        print("Already here")
    else:
        sheros.append([newname, newstat, 0, 0])

    print(sheros)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function like this.It may help you.

```
def is_elem(l, e):
    return any(e==i[0] for i in l)
```

Example

```
In [2]: sheros=[['Groot',23,34,35],['Rocket',45,56,67]]

In [3]: is_elem(sheros, 'Groot')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: is_elem(sheros, 'Other')
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: Why not just `return any(True for i in l if e==i[0])`?